# Antialias not working on pictures in python WebKit.WebView

Tags: python, html, raspberry-pi, webkit, pygtk

I have a PyGtk app with an embedded `WebKit.WebView` displaying a webpage with text and pictures. I also have a map form OpenStreetMap.

Fonts and maps are correctly antialiased, but pictures are not. 
This only happends on my Raspberry Pi 3 (because of the ARM version of WebKit I suppose)
The same app on a PC works fine

It is due to the WebKit browser or to the html page?

Any advice to get me to understand what is going on?

Is there a way to get/set the antialiasing option on the WebView so I can perform a test?

**EDIT:**

I now know it is due to WebKit. If you open a webpage into a browser in Raspbian you'll see that images are not antialiased.

I installed Chromium and the antialias is working fine with it

How to fix this?

Comment: could you provide sample code?

Comment: The question is not about code...

Comment: Is this question such stupid? I don't get why It keeps getting downvoted without any comment

Comment: I didn't downvote, but from my perspective if you could provide a minimal PyGTK app that exposes this problem you would get much better attention